# Category description in footer 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.2.4

How can I display category description in footer for all categories & it should not display in homepage

I tried below code.

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get description with below code:

```
<?php
      $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
      $Category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
      $Description = $Category ->getDescription();  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `Mage::registry`,

```
<?php 
    $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category'); 
    if(is_object($currentCategory)):
        $_description = Mage::helper("catalog/output")->categoryAttribute($currentCategory, $currentCategory->getDescription(), 'description');
?>
        <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_description; ?>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Done , but not working

Comment: Description should be different for all category but it is displaying same d for all

Comment: please clear/disable cache

Comment: @payal , in which file you add code ?

Comment: @Payaljhamta: updated code (tested and working)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will create issue  at pages.

In order to current category description.

### Solution1: using registry varible

```
<?php Mage::registry('current_category')){ ?>
<?php $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php if($_description=Mage::registry('current_category')->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute(Mage::registry('current_category'), $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php  }?>
```

### Solution2: using  layout block

```
<?php 
$CategoryVIewBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('category.products');
if($CategoryVIewBlock){
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();

?>

<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: when i add this code footer didn't diaplay